which parameter decides the energy range of transmission function in siesta-5.0.0?
I am using siesta-5.0.0
The following is my tbtrans input parameter generated by bash-script tselecs.sh from the tutorial https://github.com/zerothi/ts-tbt-sisl-tutorial
%block TBT.Contours
  IV
%endblock 
%block TBT.Contour.IV
   from -|V|/2 - 5 kT to |V|/2 + 5 kT
     delta 0.01 eV
      method mid-rule
%endblock

And here is the transmission function I got

using the following code
tbt = sisl.get_sile('./TBT_0.1/devicerelax.poscar.vasp.TBT.nc')
plt.plot(tbt.E, tbt.transmission(), label='k-averaged');
plt.xlabel('Energy [eV]'); plt.ylabel('Transmission'); plt.ylim([0, None]); plt.legend();
plt.savefig('transmission.png')

My expectation for energy range of transmission function is from -3eV to 3eV.
However, I got the energy range from -0.17428055eV to 0.17428055eV.
print(tbt.E) gives
[-0.17428055 -0.16432167 -0.15436278 -0.14440389 -0.134445   -0.12448611
 -0.11452722 -0.10456833 -0.09460944 -0.08465056 -0.07469167 -0.06473278
 -0.05477389 -0.044815   -0.03485611 -0.02489722 -0.01493833 -0.00497944
  0.00497944  0.01493833  0.02489722  0.03485611  0.044815    0.05477389
  0.06473278  0.07469167  0.08465056  0.09460944  0.10456833  0.11452722
  0.12448611  0.134445    0.14440389  0.15436278  0.16432167  0.17428055]

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

The energy range is specified via:
%block TBT.Contours
  IV
%endblock 
%block TBT.Contour.IV
   from -|V|/2 - 5 kT to |V|/2 + 5 kT
     delta 0.01 eV
      method mid-rule
%endblock

Hence here the energy range depends on:

the applied bias V (|V| is the absolute value of the applied bias)
the electronic temperature (kT), for 300 K this amounts to ~25 meV

The tutorial explains how to do a minimal calculation to extract the current (or quantities only in the Fermi-window).
If you want to always look in the energy range -3:3, simply do:
%block TBT.Contours
  line
%endblock 
%block TBT.Contour.line
   from - 3 eV to 3 eV
     delta 0.01 eV
      method mid-rule
%endblock

please note the delta value which determines the energy spacing between consecutive energy points. In the above case 10 meV.

Thank you very much! Sir.

@xinbiaowang please mark answers as correct if they fixed your problem. matter-modelling promotes users by giving up-ticks and marking things.

This answer fixes my problem! Thank you! Sir
